# Use select List Item in razor in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm going to use select list item in razor and it gives this error:

"Element 'Selectlistitem' its not supported "

@List s = sfc2.MVC.ViewModels.Category.MajorCategories();

Comment: You need to provide some more code-examples.. For instance, the code in your MajorCategories(); method

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your razor syntax is wrong. If it is a void then you'd have to use it in @{}, e.g.:

```
@{List s = sfc2.MVC.ViewModels.Category.MajorCategories();}
```

and second, yeah you should provide more code.